# How do I check if a module/class/methods has changed and log the changes?

Tags: python, unit-testing, comparison, code-analysis

I am trying to compare two modules/classes/method and to find out if the  class/method has have changed. We allow users to change classes/methods, and after processing, we make those changes persistent, without overwriting the older classes/methods. However, before we commit the new classes, we need to establish if the code has changed and also if the functionally of the methods has changed e.g output differ and performance also defer on the same input data. I am ok with performance change, but my problem is changes in code and how to log - what has changed. i wrote something like below

```
class TestIfClassHasChanged(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
       self.old = old_class()
       self.new = new_class()    
    def test_if_code_has_changed(self): 
       # simple case for one method
       old_codeobject = self.old.area.func_code.co_code
       new_codeobject = self.new.area.func_code.co_code
       self.assertEqual(old_codeobject, new_codeobject)
```

where `area()` is a method in both classes.. However, if I have many methods, what i see here is looping over all methods. Possible to do this at class or module level?

Secondly if I find that the code objects are not equal, I would like to log the changes. I used `inspect.getsource(self.old.area)` and `inspect.getsource(self.new.area)` compared the two to get the difference, could there be a better way of doing this?

Comment: `diff` and `patch`, which exist on all Unix and Unix-like systems, are your best friend.

Comment: So what you're saying is that you want a version control system in Python? How about Mercurial: http://mercurial.selenic.com/?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a version control program to help manage development.  This is one of the specific d=features you get from vc program is the ability to track changes.  You can do diffs between current source code and previous check-ins to test if there were any changes.

Comment: True VC would tract developement, but versioning control systems record file versions what i want is some form of  versioing of program entities like packages, classes, methods! at a functional level and not just changes like adding a comment.

Answer (score 0):

> if i have many methods, what i see
>   here is looping over all methods.
>   Possible to do this at class or module
>   level?

i will not ask why you want to do such thing ? but yes you can here is an example

```
import inspect
import collections

# Here i will loop over all the function in a module

module = __import__('inspect')   # this is fun !!!

# Get all function in the module.
list_functions = inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isfunction)

# Get classes and methods correspond .
list_class = inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isclass)

class_method = collections.defaultdict(list)

for class_name, class_obj in list_class:
    for method in inspect.getmembers(class_obj, inspect.ismethod):
        class_method[class_name].append(method)
```